# Change text color of a Text widget onTap

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

Im building a list from Firestore collection stream using ListViewBuilder, each item is a Text widget in the list, Im trying to change color of the text onTap the Text widget,

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

when touching/onTap Item1, text color of Item1 should be changed

I implemented using GestureDetector with setState but on onTap>setState execution, the listview of the stream is rebuilt, giving a second of blank screen/flicker and loosing the actual state since its refreshed

```
var _dynamicTextColor = Colors.green;

return ListView.builder(
                  reverse: true,
                  itemCount: itemStream.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, itemIndex) => Container(
                  child:GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          setState(() {
                            _dynamicTextColor = Colors.white;
                          });
                        },
                      child: Text(itemStream[itemIndex]['title'], style: TextStyle(color:_dynamicTextColor),),
                  ),
                ),
              );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. This will use the selected property to decide which container should be blue.

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  String selected = "first";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              selected = 'first';
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            color: selected == 'first' ? Colors.blue : Colors.transparent,
            child: Text("First"),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              selected = 'second';
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            color: selected == 'second' ? Colors.blue : Colors.transparent,
            child: Text("Second"),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it works with normal widgets as in your answer, but when stream is involved(my case) setState is causing refresh/UI rebuild

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a state management, for example Provider.
I prepared an example, I hope you understand it and solve your problem.

First, add the provider package to pubspec.yaml

```
  provider: ^4.3.3
```

Then, create a class where you will manage the states, as you would with setState. The code would be like this:

```
class ColorProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ColorProvider();
  bool isPressed = true;

  Color color = Colors.black;

  changeColor() {
    if (isPressed == true) {
      color = Colors.green;
      isPressed = false;
    } else {
      color = Colors.black;
      isPressed = true;
    }
    notifyListeners();
    return isPressed;
  }
}
```

Once this is done, you must Wrap the App material in a ChangeNotifierProvider widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/home_page.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => ColorProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And finally, call the Provider in the widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final providerWatch = context.watch<ColorProvider>();
    final providerRead = context.read<ColorProvider>();
    String text = 'This is an example text';
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            onTap: () => providerRead.changeColor(),
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(color: providerWatch.color),
            )),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

and this would be the result:

[image]